# Encapsulation questions in C#

Tags: c#, enumeration, accessor

I'm having some problems with encapsulation in C#.  There are two specific scenarios that are causing me problems and I believe the issue is related.

Scenario #1

I have a class definition that looks something like this

```
class MyClass
{
  private int _someField;
  private OtherClass _otherClass;

  public int someField
  {
    get { return _someField; }
    set { _someField = value; }
  }

  public OtherClass otherClass
  {
    get { return _otherClass; }
    set { _otherClass = value; }
  }

}
```

If I then try and do something like this in a new piece of code

```
MyClass theClass = new MyClass();

theClass.otherClass.XYZ += 1;
```

I get told Cannot Modify the return value of 'MyClass.otherClass' because it is not a variable.

Scenario 2#

```
public partial class trksegType
{

    private wptType[] trkptField;

    private extensionsType extensionsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("trkpt")]
    public wptType[] trkpt
    {
        get
        {
            return this.trkptField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.trkptField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

If I now try and foreach through the wptType array:

```
foreach (wptType way in trk.trkseg[i])
```

I get told -  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'trksegType' because 'trksegType' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Even though an array should implicitly allow enumeration.

Can anyone explain what's going on and what I can do to get around this problem, whilst still maintaining best practices.

Comment: Is the code not compiling at all or is it throwing a null error. If it's the null error, it's probably because the complex types (wptType[]/OtherClass) haven't been initialized

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you're using .NET 3 on up, you can use automatic properties instead of defining the fields behind the scenes. `public int SomeField { get; set; }`

Comment: can you show us what have you done in `Other class` so that we can have better idea

Comment: In both situations, it would depend on how you've defined `OtherClass` and `wptType`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You really shouldn’t post two questions in one.)

### Scenario 1

> Cannot Modify the return value of 'MyClass.otherClass' because it is not a variable.

This error happens because `OtherClass` is not a class, but a struct — also called a *value type*. This means that accessing `MyClass.otherClass` copies the value instead of returning a reference. You would be modifying this copy, which would be pointless. The compiler catches this because it is always a bug and never useful.

### Scenario 2

```
foreach (wptType way in trk.trkseg[i])
```

You haven’t told us what `trkseg[i]` is, but if it is of the type `trksegType`, then the answer is: because `trksegType` doesn’t allow any enumeration. It does not implement `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<T>`, nor does it have a `GetEnumerator` method of its own.

Perhaps you meant to write:

```
foreach (wptType way in trk.trkseg[i].trkpt)
```

because `trkpt` is an array of `wptType`. (You might have found this error sooner if you used more meaningful variable names instead of weird combinations of letters that make no sense.)

Comment: Thank you.  You're correct the otherClass was provided by another library and turned out not to be a class at all but a struct, also your suggestion for rewriting the foreach loop worked without issue.  The bizarre variable names came from importing an XML schema incidentally, I agree they are far from readable.

Comment: @elaverick: You might have noticed that it’s a struct instead of a class if you set Visual Studio to colour them differently. Search for “User Types” in the long listbox in the fonts/colours options; there is a separate one for structs, enums, interfaces and delegates.

Answer (score 2):

**For scenario 1,** I suspect that OtherClass has been defined as a struct. When a struct is accessed from a property accessor a new copy of the struct is created and returned (structs are [value types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)). Changing a property on this new copy will have no effect on the original struct.

The C# compiler detects this and raises that slightly obscure error.

Answer (score 2):

Scenario 1:

The reason is very likely because your `OtherClass` is a struct and not a class. Value sematics are a bit tricky and mutable value types are considered harmful. So you either want to make `OtherClass` a class and not a struct or you do something along those lines:

```
struct OtherClass
{
    public int XYZ { get; }

    public OtherClass(int xyz)
    {
         XYZ = xyz;
    }

    public OtherClass AddToXYZ(int count)
    {
         return new OtherClass(this.XYZ + count);
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
myClass.otherClass = myClass.otherClass.AddToXYZ(1);
```

Scenario 2:

You either need to implement `IEnumerable` on `trksegType` to enumerate over `trkpt` or actually access `trkpt` for the enumeration.

In General:

You have violated encapsulation in both scenarios by accessing objects through other objects. Have a look here: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson19.aspx

You also should consider using better (more explicit) names for your objects. mttng vwls ds nt ncrs rdblty.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong with your first example - so double check that the sample that errors really does and correct if not.

In the second instance, it looks like you're trying to iterate on an instance of trksegType, rather than the contained trkpt property.  Try `foreach (wptType way in trk.trkseg[i].trkpt)` instead.